# Splunk: How to extract fields directly in search bar without having to use regular expressions?

Tags: extract, splunk, splunk-query

I find it very hard to use regular expressions directly in the search bar to extract fields. Another problem is that I do not have the permission to share my extracted fields (extracted by the field extractor and stated in field extractions) with other people. I am now looking for another way to extract fields directly in the search bar. Is there something like this possible in Splunk?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions aren't so bad once you've had some practice.  Think of them as another programming language to know.

There are other ways to extract fields, but most are less efficient and all are less flexible.

The `spath` and `xpath` commands will extract fields from JSON and XML, respectively.

`multikv` extracts fields from table-formatted data (like from top).

The `extract` command can be used to parse key/value pairs into fields.

The `eval` command can be used in combination with various functions to parse events into fields.

Comment: Thanks! You are absolutely correct. They are not that bad :-D Could you maybe take a look to this question? I would need to amend it a little bit and I was wondering if this is possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64912713/how-to-modify-regular-expressions-so-that-it-extracts-same-fields-of-both-fields