# How to modify regular expressions so that it extracts same fields of both fields?

Tags: extract, splunk

When looking for some logs in one file I got two types of logs (one with white spaces and one without).
I would now like to extract *doSomething* and *doAnotherThing* out of these logs with one regular expression.

**Logfile 1:**
*"taskType":"doSomething"*

**Logfile 2:**
*"taskType" : "doAnotherThing"*

I coded this regular expression: `taskType.....(?<taskType1>\w+)`

It works good for Logfile 1 but not for Logfile 2, because it cuts the first two characters of the word. Is there a way to eliminate this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"taskType"\s?:\s?"(doSomething|doAnotherThing)"` works for me, try it here https://regex101.com/r/Mx1RtT/1

Comment: Tahnk you, and how could I modify this code in order to get any word even if it is not `doSomething` or `doAnotherThing`?

Comment: just swap doSomething|doSomethingElse to \w+ ie ```"taskType"\s?:\s?"(\w+)"```

Comment: In Regex101 I get the correct result but when applying it in Splunk I do not get any results: `source ="xyz.log" | rex field=_raw "taskType"\s?:\s?"(?<taskType1>\w+)" | stats count by taskType1`...

Comment: Be sure to escape embedded quotation marks in the `rex` command.  `rex field=_raw "taskType\\\"\s?:\s?\\\"(?<taskType1>\w+)"

Comment: Thanks for pitching in @RichG, the splunk stuff had me stumped